# Usage of train_on_batch

Tags: tensorflow, keras

What is the usage supposed to be of train_on_batch? I thought it was supposed to be as the Keras documentation states:

train_on_batch(object, x, y, class_weight = NULL, sample_weight = NULL),

but on Pat Coady's trpo code here https://github.com/pat-coady/trpo,

his implementation looks like train_on_batch([observes, actions, advantages, old_means, old_logvars, old_logp])

Comment: I guess in particular, my question is, is it required to use the Target Data (y) input for training?

Comment: Also if anyone had an explanation of how it is actually running, I'd really appreciate it. Right now from the TRPO code, I've found out that it actually calls the call function in the TRPO(Model) class twice, but I don't understand why.